# Why was this Low Quality Post not deleted with 6 votes against 1?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4769883

> **Review completed May 9 at 14:55:**
>   mmBs reviewed this May 9 at 14:55: Recommend Deletion
>   Stijn reviewed this May 9 at 14:55: Recommend Deletion
>   PaulG reviewed this May 9 at 14:52: Recommend Deletion
>   manlio reviewed this May 9 at 14:51: Recommend Deletion
>   theghostofc reviewed this May 9 at 14:50: Recommend Deletion
>   Kendrick reviewed this May 9 at 14:49: Looks Good
>   Michal Szyndel reviewed this May 9 at 14:47: Recommend Deletion

Why was the post not deleted?

Comment: [It seems like it has been removed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VcXCT.png)...

Comment: *Recommend Deletion* is not a *Delete* vote, its what's available to <20k users who do not have the delete privilege and bumps the post up in the review queue for those who do.  That said I though that 6 Recommends would cause a deletion.

Comment: @AlexK. IIRC it gets removed if the post's score is less than zero. Before the OP was able to undelete the post if it was deleted in this manner, but I'm not sure if this is still the case.

Comment: It's been converted to a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564980/css-max-width-ignoring-in-safari#comment37017885_23564980) by a moderator.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Upvoted posts are not immediately deleted from the Low Quality Posts review queue (this post had one upvote on it at time of review). Instead, they cast a "disputed low quality review (auto): Post has a good score but received delete votes" flag upon a completed review like this.

Moderators then go back through these posts and delete as we feel necessary. In many cases upvoted non-answers can point to bad reviewers or sock puppets, so it's helpful to have another set of eyes look through these before deletion.

Also, sometimes reviewers make bad calls in the Low Quality Posts queue and vote to delete good things that don't need to be removed. This acts as a safety check for that.